# Using teamviewer VPN to use internet at home?

Tags: networking, vpn, squid, teamviewer

I've been trying to configure squid to work like this thread* suggested but have been unsuccessful. Teamviewer's vpn is something like 7.xxx.xxx.xxx and it has its own adapter (not part of the local network). How can I get squid to allow/recognize teamviewer through its default http port 3128?

*[How to route internet connection through teamviewer's VPN?](https://superuser.com/questions/402223/how-to-route-internet-connection-through-teamviewers-vpn)

Comment: Configuring Squid is quite tricky, but I got the same results using Redirproxy. Try using VPN's assigned IP address instead of "hostname" when configuring the proxy server on the "client" computer.

Answer (score 1):

If by "use the internet at home" you mean simply using the home's external IP as a proxy, you'd be better off using Window's built-in [VPN connection](http://www.practicallynetworked.com/security/set-up-a-personal-windows-vpn.htm). That way you need no extra software.

Comment: Something else to remember is:  "VPNs are basically secure Internet routers."  One way to use them is to connect *to* a machine (like your work) that hosts a number of internal-only subnets which you can now reach through the VPN's provided routes, with all "other" traffic being routed elsewhere.  Another way to use them is to send *all* of your computer's traffic "through the pipe" so that it emerges onto the Internet from someplace else as though *you* were "someplace else."  You can do either or both, but be very sure that you've conceptualized what scenario you want to wind up with.