# Is it possible for me to use an app tied to my IP address when I am away from my IP address without using TeamViewer?

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy, tunnel

I use a website app inside my company which has restricted use—for security reasons—to my home static IP address. Is there a way to “borrow” my home IP address on my laptop whenever I am away from home, so I don’t have to use a TeamViewer to do my work? Some kind of tunnel or proxy using my home desktop PC.

Comment: It's an app we use inside my company. It is tied to my home address for safety, to prevent random outside access.

Comment: @Jake, my FRTIZ!Box consumer-grade modem has VPN built-in, allowing me to use my home IP address from anywhere in the world. But in this case, the OP better talk to their boss instead.

Comment: I use teamviewer but it is not very comfortable with that double scrollbars @arjan why should i talk to my boss since it is my personal home address?

Comment: [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/402223/how-to-route-internet-connection-through-teamviewers-vpn) might be useful in extending TeamViewer's VPN to achieve what you want